# Identify image size from url in python using imageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick

I'm trying to identify image dimensions from a url without downloading the whole image. I read that using imageMagick it can be done through a function called identify.

How can I use this function using python?  In python I have both wand and magickwand installed. When I'm importing into the file, I'm not really sure where that function is located (or the equivalent).

Import code (none of these provide the function):

```
from wand.image import Image
from magickwand.api import functions
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where have you read this behavior? It's true that `identify` utility will only read the "3 magick header bytes" by default, but it will follow IM's local policy & delegates. The HTTP(S) delegate will invoke `curl`; which, will download the complete image as temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagemagick's identify needs the file, you can't detect the image size without downloading the image.

Comment: From what i've read, identify downloads just enough data to get the metadata, apparently the first part of the data contains the metadata (so while you have to download it, you don't download the whole thing).

Comment: this may be true for image type but to get image size you need all of it